# I'm not able to copy Contacts from Synchronized Data Extensions to a Sendable Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions

Here is my problem :
I'm not able to copy some (58K) Contacts from a Synchronized Data Extension to a **Sendable** Standard Data Extension, with a query.

Here are some elements :

- In my connector, I have a filter which will allow contacts with the field *'DoNotSendToMc' = false* to enter into my Synchronized Data Extension called Contact_Salesforce
- Today, with Jitterbit, I changed the value of "DoNotSendToMc" from True to False, on Salesforce, on 58K Contacts. I didn't change anything on the 1 000 000 Contacts I already had before.
- Those 58K Contacts are now in my Synchronized Data Extension, and I want to send all my contacts (1 058 000) into a Standard Data Extension)
- I performed the simplest test I could :
  I created a Standard Data Extension with only 1 field called Id. I **did NOT** select "Sendable" for this Data Extension, and I populate it with a simple query

```
    SELECT Id
    FROM Contact_Salesforce
```

The result in my Data Extension is: 1 0**58** 000 Contacts. My 58 Contacts are here, I can find some of them with a search.

Then I cleared the Data Extension and changed the parameter to "Sendable", and run the same query with Overwrite.
The result in my Data Extension is: 1 0**00** 000 Contacts.

I'm missing something but for now I don't understand what check I can perform. Do you have any idea to help me ?

Thank you for your help !

Kind regards,

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be related to Contact Delete Process in your instance, where those 58k records might be in suppressed state in Contact Deletion, if those records are in suppression state then you won't get those contact keys on sendable Data Extension.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_best_practices.htm&type=5

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your answer, it seems to be a very good idea.
My "suppression period length" is already set to 0. I guess I'll need to see with the support team so they can check exactly what is happening

Comment: The support told me to check https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000313920&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1
I have to (really) delete some Contacts who had some issue when I already tried to delete them.

Comment: Final comment : support asked me what Delete process could have failed. Hoppefully I could give them some IDs. They re-ran them and told me to delete one specific sendable DE still existing, with a kind of issue with the send relationship. 
After deleting, they re-ran again and all went OK. I could retrieve my contacts in my new sendable DE